# Making a WPF DataGrid fit the content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

There are quite a few questions in regards to this topic, but after days of experimenting around, I just couldn't get it right.

All the issues listed below are a consequence of my attempts in creating a DataGrid which size fits perfectly the number of rows and columns, as well as making the cells wrap around their contents.

My attempt of creating a DataGrid is the following:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGridBulk" HeadersVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="10,83,436,477" RowBackground="LightYellow" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectedCellsChanged="DataGridBulk_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wrap" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Issue #1

- There is an extra column to the left

[image]

Issue #2

- The text within the cells is longer than the cell size. How to resize the cell?

Issue #3

- The DataGrid just looks like a dot in the designer
  This is due to `HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"`. Is there a better way to fit everything well?

The data that I'm using to fill the DataGrid:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private List<Parameter> LoadCollection()
{
    List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();

    parameters.Add(new Parameter("Schüttgewicht / Bulk density", 0, "g/cm³"));
    parameters.Add(new Parameter("Korndichte / Density", 0, "g/cm³"));
    parameters.Add(new Parameter("Korngröße / Grain size", 0, "µm"));
    parameters.Add(new Parameter("Conv. pressure Pmax abs.", 0, "mbar"));
    parameters.Add(new Parameter("Air density System (dP = 600 mbr)", 0, "kg/m³"));

    return parameters;
}
```

**Parameter.cs**

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public Parameter(string description, double value, string unit)
    {
        Description = description;
        Value = value;
        Unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the column width is less than the data because of:

```
ColumnWidth="*"
```

Try fixing it with:

```
ColumnWidth="Auto"
```

Comment: It worked! How can I get rid of the empty column on the left, though?

Comment: I think it's not row but free space, which usually on the right. But i'm not sure